# C++/C# Array shift equivilents

Tags: c#, c++, arrays

I'm trying to convert some code from C++ into C# and I'm not sure if these two statements would be equivalent.

C++ (the source):

```
float* df = new float[ length ]  // length is a previously initialized int
int coefIND = 0;
do
{
    float* const df2 = df + coefIND;
    // some element reassignments such as df2[1] = x[...] * y[...];
    coefIND += 4;
}
while(coefINF < length);
delete[] df;  // this occurs much later though
```

C# (translation?):

```
float[] df = new float[ length ]
int coefIND = 0;
do
{
     Array.Copy(df, 0, df, coefIND, length);
     // some element reassignments such as df[1] = x[...] * y[...];
     coefIND += 4;
}
while(coefIND < length)
```

Thanks for the help,
Greg

Comment: What's the problem to have some current `index` and instead of `df2[1]` write `df[index+1]`?

Comment: You haven't declared `df2` in the C# code snippet.  Also, you appear to be copying from `df2` to itself.  Also, there is no copying the first example.  How could these possibly be the same?

Comment: Also, the C++ snippet contains a memory leak.

Comment: Right. The C++ code is not copying arrays, just using a pointer to index an array. `df2 = df[coefIND]; coefIND += 4;`. And `df2[1]` becomes `df[coefIND+1]`.

Comment: I would suggest using a collection class, such as a List, rather than arrays.

Comment: Post edited, I mistyped in the c# snippet, and the delete comes later on.  Another question here ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381245/c-quickest-way-to-shift-array)) indicated that using the same array for the source and destination of Array.Copy is both the fastest way to shift the array and a new array would not need to be allocated as it would simply loop the arrays (i.e. first element moves to end, second element becomes first element, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown the C# definition of df2, but probably the best solution is to just add coefIND to each index in the body of the code, rather than copying to a temporary array (and back again afterward.)  Unlike C++, safe C# does not allow you to store a pointer to an element inside an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you are desperate to do this way you could use linq.

```
df2 = df.Skip(coefIND).ToArray();
```

However I believe that in C++ you are assuming the size of a float is 4 bytes (hence the increment by 4.

A far better implementation of the loop would just be;

```
for (var coefIND=0;coefIND<df.length;coefIND++) {
  // some element reassignments such as df[coefIND] = x[...] * y[...];
}
```

Your code is mentioning df[1] in the comment, arrays are zero index so the way you had used this would have accessed memory past the end of your array.

Comment: This would be highly inefficient, as there will be a fair amount of extra arrays being built and data being copied.

Answer (score 0):

The translation that you have provided is highly inefficient, as it requires copying of the contents of the array many times. The expression `df[ x ]` in C++ is equivalent to `*(df + x)`, and you can apply that conversion to the code to obtain:

```
float[] df = new float[ length ]
int coefIND = 0;
do
{
     // some element reassignments such as:
     df[ coefIND + 1] = x[... ] * y[...];
     coefIND += 4;
}
while(coefIND < length);
```

Note that with all of the operations in the loop being unrolled, chances are that you will have a few extra additions (compared to the C++ code) but overall the performance should be almost the same.