# Rotate a char array

Tags: c#, arrays, rotation

What are alternatives to this method

```
 tmp = c[0];
c[0] = c[1];
c[1] = c[2];
c[2] = c[3];
c[3] = tmp;
```

to left rotate a char array with 4 elements

Comment: Isn't this very similar to this question. So you want to shift the whole array left, then add the former first element to the end. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381245/c-sharp-quickest-way-to-shift-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using generics and rotating in place (thanks Jon Skeet for the suggestion):

```
static void Rotate<T>(T[] source)
{
    var temp = source[0];
    Array.Copy(source, 1, source, 0, source.Length - 1);
    source[source.Length - 1] = temp;
}
```

These should work for any array of at least 2 length, and on any array.

If performance is critical and the arrays are always small, use this:

```
static void Rotate<T>(T[] source)
{
    var temp = source[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length - 1; i++)
        source[i] = source[i + 1];
    source[source.Length - 1] = temp;
}
```

The first method is the fastest with large arrays, but for 4 items, this one's almost as fast as your example method.

Comment: Any reason why you didn't rotate in place, as per the OP's original code? (Array.Copy works fine with that.)

Comment: I didn't think of that.  I'll make that edit as an alternate way to do it.

Comment: Good but it's two time slower than the simple c[0] = c[1];

Comment: Is the performance of this actually a problem in your program?  Don't micro-optimize when you don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

An alterantive to rotating the array, is to rotate the index when accessing the array, i.e you are creating a virtual ring

```
int origin = someValue;
int x = c[(i + origin) % c.Length];
```

Comment: Good but, i'm looking for physical rotation

Answer (score 0):

Do the job in single step.

```
Using System.Linq;

 int[]  ar = { 1,2,3,4,5};
 int k = 1; //
 int[] ar1=  ar.Skip(k)            // Start with the last elements
             .Concat(ar.Take(k)) // Then the first elements
             .ToArray();
```

Output-- 2,3,4,5,1

Comment: im looking for a rotation not a shift

Comment: does not work for more than 5 (i.e. Length of array) or for negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're asking for a more efficient method or for an easier way to type that, but i'm going to try answering you assuming you want an easier way

so try:

```
int temp = c[0]
for(int i = 0; i < c.count; i++)
{
    if (i == (c.count - 1))
    {
        c[i] = temp;
        break;
    }
    c[i] = c[i + 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ruby rotating array can be done in one line.

```
def array_rotate(arr)
    i, j = arr.length - 1, 0
    arr[j],arr[i], i, j = arr[i], arr[j], i - 1, j + 1 while(j<arr.length/2)
    puts "#{arr}"
end
```