# Shifting One Array Into/Onto Another Fixed Size Array From Left Or Right

Tags: c#, arrays, lcd, .net-micro-framework

I've been thinking about this for a while and keep falling back on nested For Loops and a bunch of If/Thens...

I am trying to create a text scrolling/slide-in effect for a LCD Character Display on a single line. I would like to be able to set the input start point and end point into the array. For example, I have a base byte array size of 16 and want to start to shift an array onto/into it.

Output would be something like this with each line being an iteration of the array which is sent to the display:

_______________ <-start with blank array[16]

_____________H_ <-start to shift in at specified start position e.g. [14]

____________He_

___________Hel_

__________Hell_

_________Hello_

________Hello__

_______Hello___

______Hello____

_____Hello_____ <-end shifting as specified position e.g. [5]

Conversely, I would like to be able to shift this out like so:

_____Hello_____ <-Begining Array <-This needs to be created

____Hello______

___Hello_______

__Hello________

_Hello_________

_ello__________

_llo___________

_lo____________

_o_____________

_______________

Is there an efficient/native way to do this? I'm using NetMF so there are some limitations to the framework.

footnote: I suppose this could be done by directly manipulating the string to be displayed then I convert it to a byte array to send to the display but I think this might be slower.

Comment: There maybe some relevant ideas here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381245/c-sharp-quickest-way-to-shift-array

Comment: Thanks..I've read through that before posting this, but I still haven't quite grasped how to apply that to my case just yet..working on it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  class Program2
    {
        static void AnimateString(int leftEdge, int RightEdge, int length, char fillWith, string text, int delay_ms)
        {
            int x = RightEdge;
            string line = "";
            int count = 0;
            string leftBorder = "";            

        while (true)
        {
            Console.CursorLeft = 0;
            Console.Write(new String(fillWith, length));
            Console.CursorLeft = 0;

            if (x < leftEdge) ++count;                

            leftBorder = new String(fillWith, x - 1 > leftEdge ? x - 1 : leftEdge);                

            line = leftBorder + text.Substring(
                    x > leftEdge - 1? 0 : count, 
                    x > leftEdge - 1 ? (x + text.Length > RightEdge ? RightEdge - x : text.Length) : text.Length - count);
            Console.Write(line);
            Thread.Sleep(delay_ms);
            --x;
            if (count >= text.Length) { x = RightEdge; count = 0; line = ""; }
        }       
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        string blank = new String('-', 32);
        string text = "Hello world!";
        AnimateString(4, 20, 24, '-', "Hello world", 100);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Check this line of code:

```
line = leftBorder + text.Substring(
        x > leftEdge - 1? 0 : count, 
        x > leftEdge - 1 ? (x + text.Length > RightEdge ? RightEdge - x : text.Length) : text.Length - count);
```

We already created the 'left part' of our string - line of text starts with 0 and ends either with position of x or left border (in case when x - leftEdge is less than zero. Now it's time to calculate: 1) what index in text ('hello world') should we take for SubString method and 2) how many characters we'd like to extract.

1) depends on : has our x position reached the left border ?
   no) we start from index 0
   yes) we start from count value. Count - is our field that we use to calculate 
the left shift inside our text string

2) this depends on position of x against right border. If our x position + text string.length are not exceeding the borders we'd take that string. In other case we should count how many characters are within the limits and extract them. Also if x - leftEdge < 0 and we started from index of count - we'd like to subtract count value from string length so we get only the remaining part of a string and not exceeding it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is a head great head start on my code! It took a little while to understand all that you're doing in the `line=...` statement. I modified and rewrote it so it's more clear to me...I was also wondering if there was some more efficient way to accomplish this with byte/char arrays

Comment: String is just a char array so you can work with it as with any array using LINQ. But LINQ is considerably slower in terms of performance. Reason it was created is to provide easy 'on fly' language that is used to query any source of ienumerable data such as Dbs or Collections (or Arrays). That's why it's slow. It's not the best choice in your case.

Comment: Edited my answer and explained the algorithm i used