# Shift property values of objects in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I currently have a working method that shifts the values of one property of objects in an array:

```
    public class Group
    {
        public Position[] Positions { get; private set; }

        public void Shift()
        {
            var last = Positions[Count - 1].Tile;
            for( int i = Count - 1 ; i > 0 ; i-- )
            {
                // Note this shifts Tile value and not the array itself
                Positions[i].Tile = Positions[i - 1].Tile;
            }
            Positions[0].Tile = last;
        }
    }

    public class Position
    {
        // [other properties]

        public Tile Tile { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem is that this method needs to run a lot in an algorithm and it is the one that consumes most CPU time.

I'm searching for a better way to shift these values and found BlockCopy in this excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52465132/1554208

But it's used to shift the array itself. Is there a way to copy the content of a property (here a simple pointer)?

I'm open to:

- Use unsafe pointer methods
- Change the Position class if needed
- Any other suggestion

**EDIT**

Is there some way to "calculate" the size in bytes of a Position object, "calculate" the address of the Tile property within that object, and use something like Buffer.BlockCopy to copy these values at that specific address in the array?

Comment: How about have a references to `Tile` in an array and shift that.

Comment: Position is a necessary layer. One Position can be in multiple Groups. If a Tile change for a Position, it must change in all the groups.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it by Array.Copy in C#

```
public class Group
{
    public Position[] Positions { get; private set; }

    public void ShiftRight()
    {
        Array.Copy(Positions,0,Positions,1,Positions.Length-1);//Right
        Positions[0].Tile=null;

        Array.Copy(g,1,g,0,g.Length-1);
    }
    public void ShiftLeft()
    { 
        Array.Copy(Positions,1,Positions,0,Positions.Length-1)
        Positions[Positions.Length-1].Tile=null;
    }
}

public class Position
{
    // [other properties]

    public Tile Tile { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No. This will shift the entiore Positions array, but it cannot move. Positions must keep the same index in the array. Only the Tiles inside them must shift.